# Imagemagick mogrify android 9-patch png

Tags: android, imagemagick, nine-patch

I have a nine-patch png, Then I use `mogrify -resample` to resample that png. But seems the 9-patch border is wrong.

> How can I resample(or something else) that image and keeping the 9-patch border the same as original one.

Comment: Seems such tools not exists

Answer (score 4):

You can use ImageMagik to do what you want.

Basically, you need to remove the existing 9-patch markers/border, resample/resize the image, and then put the 9-patch markers/border back.

Steps:

1. crop off the old 1-pixel-thick border (-crop command)
2. resample/resize the image (-resize command)
3. add a transparent border (-matte -bordercolor none -border 1)
4. draw you 9-patch markers onto the new border (e.g. -fill black -draw "line 16,0 17,0" -draw "line 0,16 0,17")
5. save the result

Example batch file line (doesn't do step 1, so you'll need to figure that out yourself):

```
convert -background none foobar.svg -resize 32x32 -matte -bordercolor none -border 1 -fill black -draw "line 16,0 17,0" -draw "line 0,16 0,17" foobar.9.png
```